# Watson Natural Language Understanding - set Language

Tags: java, watson

I am using the Watson Natural Language Understanding to analyze entities from different texts. Is there a way to set the language of the text, like it was possible for the Alchemy API?

```
service.setLanguage (LanguageSelection.ENGLISH);
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can override the automatic language detection in NLU by specifying a language code in the language attribute of the parameters JSON object.

From the [documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/natural-language-understanding/overriding-language-detection.html#overriding-language-detection):

```
{
  "text": "...this is some text",
  "features": {
    "semantic_roles": {}
  },
  "language": "en"
}

curl -X POST \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-u "{username}":"{password}" \
-d @parameters.json \
"https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-understanding/api/v1/analyze?version=2017-02-27"
```